# Why sparklines are outside of table as expected?

Tags: pandas

Bonjour,

"sparkline" does not work in my code.
Already, I didn't manage to install it. So, I found a function that I call "sparkline_test. Nevertheless, the images that should be integrated in the table are outside. Something is wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
from itertools import islice
import seaborn as sns
import base64
```

I cannot import sparklines:
#import sparklines

```
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
    def percentile_90(x):
    return x.quantile(.9)

from scipy.stats import trim_mean
def trim_mean_10(x):
    return trim_mean(x, 0.1)

def largest(x):
    return x.nlargest(1)

def sparkline_str(x):
    bins=np.histogram(x)[0]
    sl = ''.join(sparklines(bins))
    return sl

def sparkline_test(data, figsize=(4,0.25),**kwags):
    data = list(data)
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=figsize,**kwags)
    ax.plot(data)
    
    for k,v in ax.spines.items():
        v.set_visible(False)
    
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    
    plt.plot(len(data)-1, data[len(data)-1], 'r.')
    
    ax.fill_between(range(len(data)), data, len(data)*[min(data)], alpha=0.1)
    
    img = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(img, transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
    img.seek(0)
    plt.show()
#    plt.close()
    
    return base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode("utf-8")

def sparkline_str(x):
    bins=np.histogram(x)[0]
    sl = ''.join(sparkline_test(bins))
    return sl

agg_func_largest = {
    'fare': [percentile_90, trim_mean_10, largest, sparkline_test]
    #'fare': [percentile_90, trim_mean_10, largest]
}
df.groupby(['class', 'embark_town']).agg(agg_func_largest)
```

that produces:

[image]

What is expected is:

[image]

Something is wrong....But what?
Do you have any idea?
Regards,
Atapalou